# Java library for parsing out MAPI properties from an Exchange binary property?

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi

I've been doing some work on an Exchange project using the EWS Managed API for Java.

Recently, I ran into a particular property that was a `RecipientRow` formatted as a binary property, which comes through as a byte array. I was able to pick through it and find the necessary property by searching the array for particular MAPI tags, but now I have to wonder if there's currently a free Java library out there that can be used to simplify this process.

Basically, it would only need to be some convenience methods/objects wrapped around a large "map" of property tags to type and other attributes for each tag (i.e. `0x1F000330` is a `String` property that represents an email address and is variable length). An extreme example would be using the `ExportItems` function to dump an entire Exchange object into a base 64 encoded string and then pick through it for all properties. I imagine that anything designed to interface with MAPI or parse data from Outlook would need to do something like this, but is the code freely available?

I'm not talking about picking open any binary stream from Exchange. This is largely specific to EWS, where any binary data would have been requested. `RecipientRows` are handled with this tagging method, and having a map of tags, types, and other attributes can allow you to pick apart a `RecipientRow` and handle the values.

I would presume that `ExportItems` would follow the same format, prepended with header information and flags, then providing a large chunk of binary data with tags identifying particular values within. I could be mistaken as I have not yet tried using `ExportItems` (it's not built into the EWS Managed API, but it is supported by Exchange, so I would need to build it in), so I can't say for certain. But given the structure that Microsoft uses for multi-property binary values, it may well be valid in this particular case.

Attachments and such would need to be handled in a more generic fashion, of course, but information on Exchange items (ie, the recipients for an Appointment, the body of an email, etc) should be accessible.

Comment: Which particular property are you working with? Most of the binary properties formats are documented on MSDN.

Comment: Any and all. I've been through plenty of documentation and I can parse out things specifically, but I'm looking for a more general library with all of the information collected and constructed so that, say, you could pass it a byte array and it would give you a Map<PropertyDefinition, Object> back, or an ExchangeObject that wraps the unpacked properties, or something to that effect, maybe even tying in with EWS Java and placing all properties into a new ServiceObject child class.

Comment: This is not possible even in theory - there is no common format for binary properties, each one is different. You need to know the blob format to be able to parse it.

Comment: I'm not talking about digging through an existing local/remote Outlook inbox as MFCMAPI would. I'm looking more specifically at properties retrieved via EWS, largely via the ExportItems method, although others that return multiple pieces of data in a binary format would suffice. I could see this being a very ugly issue if you wanted to dice up any possible file/format/source of any file type in Outlook/Exchange/Anything related, but I would think that it should be doable if the focus is on one particular format or source.

Comment: Again, *which* property? There is no common format. It is like saying that any array that contains arbitrary data can be parsed in a generic way. You can have an MP3 file data, or a JPEG, or something completely custom.